# $f:[0,1\to\mathbb{R}]$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that exists $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I'm reading a proof that:

$f:[0,1\to\mathbb{R}]$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that exists $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})$

It says the follwing:

> Define $\phi(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})-f(x)$. Then,
>   $\phi(0)+\phi(\frac{1}{2})=0$ (I understood this part). Then, exists
>   $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})$

well, in the last part, I know that he used the intermediate value theorem, so I'm trying to find where did he prove that $f(0)<f(x+\frac{1}{2})<f(\frac{1}{2})$ in order for the theorem to be applied (because there should be $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})$.

So, where is $f(0)<f(x+\frac{1}{2})<f(\frac{1}{2})$ ?

Comment: So...$\phi(0)=-\phi(\frac 12)$.  If $\phi(0)=0$ then $x=0$ gets the job done.  If $\phi(0)\neq 0$ then $\phi$ changes sign on $[0,\frac 12]$ hence vanishes somewhere on that interval.

Comment: f is continuous right?

Comment: Did you mean $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: Um. $\phi (0) =- \phi(1/2) $.  So there must be an x in [0,1/2] where $\phi (x) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** If $\phi(0) = \phi(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$, then the claim is true. Otherwise since $\phi(0) + \phi(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$ one of them is negative and the other one is positive, so by IVT somewhere in between the graph of $\phi$ has to intersect the $x$-axis, as $\phi$ is continuous.